# How to query for things that are due tomorrow but getting the 'syntax error '

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) want to query the database that meets the condition of the `current_date` being a day before the `endDate`, basically things that are due tomorrow, but I'm getting the following error:

> error: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone - integer

My code:

```js
    const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "Booking" LEFT JOIN "User" ON ("Booking"."renter"="User"."id") WHERE "endDate" - 1 = current_date')
```

I also tried the following, but the same error:

```js
     const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "Booking" LEFT JOIN "User" ON ("Booking"."renter"="User"."id") WHERE extract(EPOCH FROM "endDate" - 1) = current_date')
```

I then tried:

```js
const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "Booking" LEFT JOIN "User" ON ("Booking"."renter"="User"."id") WHERE date_trunc(endDate) = date_trunc(current_timestamp + INTERVAL "1 day")')
```

I get the error

> error: syntax error at or near ""1 day""

If I eliminate the quotation, I get:

> error: syntax error at or near "1"

Comment: The correct syntax is `inter val '1 day'`.

Comment: I get `error: syntax error at or near "val"`

Comment: @Kevvv That should be `interval '1 day'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"endDate"` is not, as you seem to expect, a date, but a timestamp, and you cannot subtract integers from it. You can subtract an interval, but that's not what you want.

You should compare like this:

```
WHERE "endDate" >= CAST (current_date + 1 AS timestamp)
  AND "endDate" <  CAST (current_date + 2 AS timestamp)
```

That condition has the added advantage that it can be supported by an index on `"endDate"`.

Comment: why not `WHERE "endDate" = CAST (current_date + 1 AS timestamp)`?

Comment: Because `"endDate"` may contain a time other than midnight.

Comment: ah ok. Can you explain CAST? It seems to be a function to convert the date to an integer, but why are we converting a timestamp to an integer?

Comment: Cast is not a function converting a date to an integer. It is more of a directive to Postgres to transform one datatype to another datatype (datatype AS datatype) providing a suitable transformation is found. You can even [create your own](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createcast.html). Postgres likes comparing datatypes that are the same. You can add integers to dates to produce another date. Since your column endDate is defined as a timestamp the CAST is used to transform current_date+1 from a date into a timestamp.

Comment: @Kevvv A cast converts between data types (you are right, there is usually a function behind it). In this case, a `date` is converted to a `timestamp without time zone`, which results in a timestamp at midnight of that day.